# Transforming Point Cloud

Tags: transforms, pcl, tf2, pcl-ros, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to transform a Point Cloud from one frame to another. I'm using the method:

```
transformPointCloud (const std::string &target_frame, const tf::Transform &net_transform, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 &in, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 &out)
```

I have built a transform tree and it works great. I can see well transformed image in rviz using base_link as map. I need to do some calculations on the PointCloud2 data so i need the points transformed to camera_depth frame. However when I use this method I'm not getting the result needed when I visualize the camera_depth, the image is tilted and not straight as in base_link.

```
listener.lookupTransform(*camera_depth, *base_link, ros::Time(0), transform);

pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(*camera_depth, transform, *msg, *msgOut);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205236/transforming-point-cloud/) by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2015-03-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I needed to invert the transform.

```
pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(*camera_depth, transform.invert(), *msg, *msgOut);
```

Solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [RosFan19](https://answers.ros.org/users/21450/rosfan19/) with karma: 107 on 2015-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-04-26**:
That would be because the API for lookupFrame is:

> lookupTransform (const std::string &target_frame, const std::string &source_frame ..)

So it would be more sensible to have *camera_depth as your source frame, and *base_link as your target frame. Didn't catch that.